# NestJS cli very slow in Docker container on Windows with Visual Studio Code

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, nestjs

The response from the `nest` cli command from NestJS (`npm i -g @nestjs/cli`) in a Docker Development container with Visual Studio Code on Windows 10 is suddenly very slow. At first it works fine but at some point, for instance after deleting a directory in the `src` folder, the `nest` command gets very slow.

Example:

```
node ➜ /workspaces/Servers/terminal-server (master ✗) $ time nest --help

[...]

real    0m44.576s
user    0m6.239s
sys     0m4.407s
```

Yarn is used for the package manager. NPM is used to install nest cli globally (`npm i -g @nestjs/cli`):

| Software | Version | Running in container | Running on W10 host |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NPM | 8.1.2 | X |  |
| NodeJS | v16.13.1 | X |  |
| Yarn | 1.22.15 | X |  |
| Typescript | 4.5.2 | X |  |
| Nest | 8.1.6 | X |  |
| Visual Studio Code | 1.63.2 |  | X |
| Docker Desktop | 4.3.1 |  | X |

It looks like the line `const localCommandLoader = local_binaries_1.loadLocalBinCommandLoader();` in `/usr/local/share/npm-global/bin/nest` is causing the delay.

Edit:
Compiling is also very slow. As you can see, it started at 8:57:20 and finished at 9:00:17. And this is compiling the default scaffolding.

```
[8:57:20 AM] Starting compilation in watch mode...

[8:59:43 AM] Found 0 errors. Watching for file changes.

[Nest] 5197  - 12/23/2021, 9:00:17 AM     LOG [NestFactory] Starting Nest application...
[Nest] 5197  - 12/23/2021, 9:00:17 AM     LOG [InstanceLoader] AppModule dependencies initialized +67ms
[Nest] 5197  - 12/23/2021, 9:00:17 AM     LOG [RoutesResolver] AppController {/}: +42ms
[Nest] 5197  - 12/23/2021, 9:00:17 AM     LOG [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/, GET} route +8ms
[Nest] 5197  - 12/23/2021, 9:00:17 AM     LOG [NestApplication] Nest application successfully started +8ms
```

I did the same on WSL:

```
[10:03:48 AM] Starting compilation in watch mode...

[10:03:53 AM] Found 0 errors. Watching for file changes.

[Nest] 1998  - 12/23/2021, 10:03:54 AM     LOG [NestFactory] Starting Nest application...
[Nest] 1998  - 12/23/2021, 10:03:54 AM     LOG [InstanceLoader] AppModule dependencies initialized +62ms
[Nest] 1998  - 12/23/2021, 10:03:54 AM     LOG [RoutesResolver] AppController {/}: +14ms
[Nest] 1998  - 12/23/2021, 10:03:54 AM     LOG [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/, GET} route +6ms
[Nest] 1998  - 12/23/2021, 10:03:54 AM     LOG [NestApplication] Nest application successfully started +9ms
```

For the Docker image I've selected the `Node.js & TypeScript` image. Would it be better to just use a plain image and install everything manually?

Or is there a way to get the response time of `nest` normal again?

Comment: When you say it used to be fast and is now slow, are you sure that it wasn't just being cached before, which seems fast, and now it is actually compiling that it is slow? There is a common problem with docker and npm, in that depending on which cache layers you lose, the npm install has to download everything again and it can be slow. The only thing you can do afaik is push the npm part as early as possible in the dockerfile to minimise the number of rebuilds.

Comment: Well setting up the application with `nest new projectname` was fast. The packages where already installed using yarn. NPM was only used to install the nest cli globally. Then I created a controller but it had a typo. Removed the files, created the controller again with `nest g controller name` and then it got real slow.

Comment: I'm running into virtually the exact same situation. node:16.13.1-alpine3.14, NestJS v8.1. Between saving a file and have the server restart is ~2 mins, virtually unusable.

Comment: can you show the output of [`tsc --extendedDiagnostics`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Performance#extendeddiagnostics)

Comment: Could do that, but even showing the help from the nest cli is slow. Or does it get compiled runtime with tsc?

Comment: Im having same issue.. hopefuly a real answer will come soon

Comment: I have the same issue on Mac.

Answer (score 6):

**TL;DR** If you insist on booting into Windows for development but want to use VSCode and dev containers, try doing it all inside a Linux VM as I got a 96% reduction in time taken for key dev task steps.

**Summary**

I get a **96% reduction on startup / recompile time** of a dev-container NestJS TypeScript project on `npm run start:dev` when **running in a linux VM inside Windows 10** vs VSCode directly Windows 10 with docker and wsl2. ie **7s** vs **2m 50s**

**Dev Containers**

I think dev containers are great, love using them on github codespaces, but found the experience on Win 10 to be painfully slow.

In a multi developer team dev containers can offer a consistent experience between developers and reduce the risk of different setups on different developers' machines. But that's worthless if it takes more than a few seconds to rebuild the app everytime you save a file while running in 'watch' mode.

**What slows NestJS / TypeScript in Dev Containers**

After various investigations I'm convinced the speed penalty is in the dev container accessing the hosts filesystem.

NestJS cli is frustratingly eager to load everything it can do, before it even parses the command line args, so that's a big hit if filesystem access is slow.

And then the TypeScript compilation is obviously heavily dependent on filesystem speed. So this is the other area that grinds to a halt. Even on a relatively small NestJS project with few additional external dependencies!

**What's fastest**

Running Linux inside a VM on my Windows machine, running VSCode and docker all inside that VM meant that the filesystem access between the commands running inside the dev container (in docker inside the linux VM) can access the code 'hosted' on the linux VM very quickly.

**Comparison Table**

| Activity | Codespaces Browser | Codespaces Win10 remote | VSCode + Win Docker on Win 10 with WSL2 | VSCode + docker in Linux VM in Win 10 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `npx nest i` | 1.16s | 1.16s | 14.2s | 1.12s |
| `npm run start:dev` *startup* | 10s | 8s | 170s | 7s |
| `npm run start:dev` *update a file* | 3s | 2s | 38s | 2s |
| `rm -rf node_modules ; time npm install` | 30s | 28s | 85s | 27s |

Setups used:

- Codespaces

  - 2core 4GB instance
- Win 10

  - AMD Ryzen 7 3700X 8 Core @ 4.16GHz
  - 64GB 2400MHz RAM
  - 1TB SSD
  - Internet: 27Mb down / 5Mb up
- Linux VM (inside Win 10 above)

  - VMware 16.2.3
  - Ubuntu 22.04
- dev container is the recommended Node.js & Typescript container with VARIANT: "16-bullseye"

  - with mariadb server running inside

To get an active-developer experience, I ran each command a few times until the timing settled down and recorded the most representative time...

- anything that doesn't use 'time' in the command was done by hand and so has a +/- 1sec error
- `time npx nest i`

  - the time the command shows at the end
- `npm run start:dev` *startup*

  - timing is from hitting enter to the first log of `LOG [NestFactory] Starting Nest application...`
- `npm run start:dev` *update a file*

  - timing is from saving an update to a watched file, to the next log of `LOG [NestFactory] Starting Nest application...`
- `rm -rf node_modules ; time npm install`

  - just another filesystem dependent task to compare the environments
  - the time the command shows at the end

Answer (score 1):

As @Rob Baily suggested, executing the script in WSL while the files are in windows is very slow.

From [a microsoft/WSL issue](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/5078#issuecomment-613384302):

> (...) /mnt/c is your Windows drive, so WSL2 accesses files from Windows via a proxy, not directly. Copy all project files from /mnt/c/.../example-nextjs to /home/user, so that it is stored in WSL2 virtual machine.

I did that and it's very simple to [run VS Code from a WSL folder](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/wsl) if you want:

```bash
mkdir -p ~/projects/foo
cp -Rf /mnt/c/projects/foo ~/projects/foo
```

Then run VS Code on the new folder:

```bash
cd ~/projects/foo
code .
```

From now on, you are actually running the code in the WSL VM, so you don't need to manage a separate Linux VM on your computer.

After doing this, running `npm run start:dev` takes only a few seconds for me (compared to several minutes when the files were on `/mnt/..`) and now ***--watch actually works***!

Comment: This kind of did the trick, however, it only worked for me running `docker-compose`, not `npm run start:dev` as it throws an UNC error. But now `docker-compose` with hot reload works fine and fast, not the unusable speed from windows

Answer (score 0):

I have been experiencing this as well and wanted to expand on the info above based on my experience.  VS Code has a WSL extension which lets you open WSL folders in code which allows you to see better performance on the file system.  See https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/wsl for reference.  Here are the steps I used to be able to make it work:

- Install Ubuntu 20 from the Microsoft Store for a WSL distro.  You can install it other ways I believe.  I tried 22 and it did not work but not sure if that was because I did something else wrong so you could try it and see.
- Enable WSL integration for the new distro with Docker Desktop.  Reference https://docs.docker.com/desktop/windows/wsl/ for some information on this.
- Install the WSL extension for VS Code.  See first link above.
- As noted in both links above the way to start is open up a WSL terminal, cd to the directory you want to run VS Code in and type `code .`  It is also possible to do it from the VS Code interface as well as noted in the VS Code post.
- From there if you have your .devcontainer folder already setup you can reopen the folder in a dev container and away you go!
- If you need to access any of the files through Windows you can go to the \wsl$ network path and access them there.

This feels a little convoluted but it seems this is the supported way for now based on what I read.  Perhaps in the future the WSL2 to Windows file system interface will be improved to a point where this is not necessary.

Happy to hear any feedback or update this based on other's experiences.